# Animated CSS not strolling with page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new on css, html and javascript. Trying to create a website but stuck on animation.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700');

body{
  background-color: rosybrown;
}

header{
    background-color: black;
    height: 20%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;

    
}

#fly-in {

  height: 50px;

  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 40vh auto;
  height: 20vh; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#fly-in span {
  display: block;
  font-size: .4em;
  opacity: .8;
}

#fly-in div {
 position: fixed; 
 background-position: 50%;
  margin: 2vh 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 10vw;
  width: 80vw;
  animation: switch 32s linear infinite;
}

#fly-in div:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 4s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 8s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 12s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 16s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 20s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: 24s}
#fly-in div:nth-child(8) { animation-delay: 28s}

@keyframes switch {
    0% { opacity: 0;filter: blur(20px); transform:scale(12)}
    3% { opacity: 1;filter: blur(0); transform:scale(1)}
    10% { opacity: 1;filter: blur(0); transform:scale(.9)}
    13% { opacity: 0;filter: blur(10px); transform:scale(.1)}
    80% { opacity: 0}
    100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="fly-in">  
        <div><span>Very</span>Cinematic</div>
        <div>Fade Away<span>into the distance</span></div>
        <div>Still Loops <span> for eternity</span></div>
        <div><span>Just CSS</span> and HTML</div>
        <div><span>Very</span>Cinematic</div>
        <div>Fade Away<span>into the distance</span></div>
        <div>Still Loops <span> for eternity</span></div>
        <div><span>Just CSS</span> and HTML</div>
    </div>
</header>

<div>
  <H1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Ab sit debitis error deleniti, 
      molestias consectetur nostrum cupiditate possimus 
      neque nemo adipisci aut a minima iste ipsam deserunt 
      incidunt iure aliquid?</H1>

   <H1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
       adipisicing elit. Ab sit debitis error deleniti, 
       molestias consectetur nostrum cupiditate possimus 
       neque nemo adipisci aut a minima iste ipsam deserunt 
       incidunt iure aliquid?</H1>

   <H1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
       adipisicing elit. Ab sit debitis error deleniti, 
       molestias consectetur nostrum cupiditate possimus 
       neque nemo adipisci aut a minima iste ipsam deserunt 
       incidunt iure aliquid?</H1>

  <H1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Ab sit debitis error deleniti,
      molestias consectetur nostrum cupiditate possimus
      neque nemo adipisci aut a minima iste ipsam deserunt
      incidunt iure aliquid?</H1>
  <H1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Ab sit debitis error deleniti,
      molestias consectetur nostrum cupiditate possimus
      neque nemo adipisci aut a minima iste ipsam deserunt
      incidunt iure aliquid?</H1>
  <H1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Ab sit debitis error deleniti,
      molestias consectetur nostrum cupiditate possimus
      neque nemo adipisci aut a minima iste ipsam deserunt
      incidunt iure aliquid?</H1>
</div>
```

animation works well but what i want is when i stroll down animation should follow the page and go up. but thats not happen. I have changed position to relative, sticky and fixed but no luck.

codepin: https://codepen.io/younusrahman/pen/QWvpKXE

Comment: Please don't put code in links. Include the *relevant* part of the code in the question.

Comment: i am trying to remove links but getting error

Comment: error : Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: You place the code itself (i.e. copy the relevant code from codepen and paste it in the question). Please also read how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Changing the values of `position` won't fix the issue. I tried giving `position: relative`, now the text is getting moved up on scroll, but each texts are coming after another. If you have only one text, this would work.

Comment: So there is no way to put more then one text if i want to work with scroll? :(

Comment: Not as I checked. Or you can do one thing. Try wrapping the div's in another div with position relative and give position absolute to the inner div's. I don't know if it will workout. You can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Set div position to absolute inside "fly-in" div instead of fixed

```
#fly-in div 
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Many many thnx, I tried it thought but it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: One more question. is it possible to hide the scroll bar? .At the beginning of all the text it shows a scroll bar below. how can i delete or hide this scroll bar?

Comment: Add overflow hidden to your body ie: body{ overflow-x:hidden;}

Comment: I am glad it helped :)